# html and Javascript code is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have 2 html file that makes 5 button with a video linked with it. The video linked with the buttons are stored locally in my computer in a folder named video. the folder is in the same directory as the 2 html files.

when i click on the button it suppose open the page3.html and play the video in page3.html but when i click on the button it is opening page3.html but it seems it can't locate any video

1st one is index.html and the code in it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>index.html</h1>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="video1">Video 1</button>
            <button id="video2">Video 2</button>
            <button id="video3">Video 3</button>
            <button id="video4">Video 4</button>
            <button id="video5">Video 5</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons button");
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    var videoId = this.id;
                    var videoUrl = "video/" + videoId + ".mp4";
                    window.location.href = "page3.html?video=" + videoId;
                    
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2nd one is page3.html and the code for it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page3.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page3.html</h1>
        <video width="560" height="315" controls>
        <source src="video/{{video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i click on the button it suppose open the page3.html and play the video in page3.html but when i click on the button it is opening page3.html but it seems it can't locate any video

Comment: You don't use your variable `videoUrl`, maybe you meant to use it in the query string instead of `videoId` ?

Comment: And in the second file, does something takes care of replacing the `{{video}}` substring ? How do you handle the parameter in your querystring ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTML doesn't know what this part means: `<source src="video/{{video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">` as far as i know you need a framework like react or angular to understand this {{}} part.

So you need a javascript part to replace the value of source. Your javascript could look like something below.

```
const videoSource = urlParams.get('video');
const videoUrl = 'video/' + videoSource + '.mp4';
const sourceElement = document.querySelector('video source');
sourceElement.src = videoUrl;
```

You can also use [setAttribute function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) of Javascript.